# JS: incremental counter without setting a counter variable in the global scope?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set an internal counter that adds 1 every time the user clicks on a link that triggers an onclick function. It starts at 0 and everytime the user clicks on the link the counter will increase by 1 (or whatever integer you want). The counter should reset to 0 upon refresh and the variable that holds the integer value cannot be declared in the global scope.

I keep running into the catch22 of how to initially declare the variable without this declaration being repeated everytime the function runs, essentially setting the counter value back to the original value.

Comment: Why can't the variable be declared globally?

Comment: Showing some code of yours might help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that's what you're after, but here are 2 ways of doing what you want:

```
// method 1: use a private scope
var click_handler = (function() {
    var counter = 0; // this is not in global scope!
    return function() {
        counter++;
    };
})();

// method 2: use a function property
function click_handler() {
    click_handler.counter++;
}
click_handler.counter = 0;
```

Comment: The closure (first example) is preferred. Adding properties to functions as pseudo global variables is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? here the counter is a local variable and the onclick function is defined in the same scope as that of the counter variable. Also everytime it refreshes the counter will be reset to 0.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Link Counter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = init

    function init() {
        var counter = 0
        var link = document.getElementById("link")
        var display = document.getElementById("display")
        function increase_counter() {
            counter++
            display.innerHTML = counter
            return false

        }

        link.onclick = increase_counter

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="" id="link">Click Here </a>
    <p id="display">0 </p>
</body>

</html>
```